# Bulk update by query in Elastic Search?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I know that Elastic Search does not currently support bulk updating by query because of Lucene, but are there any alternatives that don't involve installing an ElasticSearch extension?

For example, are there any workarounds to performing:

```
UPDATE users SET temp = 1 WHERE temp = 0;
```

Using the bulk method? Or some other method that I don't know about?

I'm new to Elastic Search as an entity so I don't know the ins and outs, but I have read a lot about its ability to update one at a time, but that would be too time consuming with hundreds of thousands of rows.

Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

`update_by_query` was added to elasticsearch in version 2.3.

> The update-by-query API is new and should still be considered
> experimental. The API may change in ways that are not backwards
> compatible.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-update-by-query.html

It seems like you need to write a script for the update portion, so it's a bit of a pain.

```
UPDATE users SET temp = 1 WHERE temp = 0;
```

==>

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "temp": 0
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.temp = 1"
    }
}
```

Note: For this inline script version to work, you'll need inline scripts enabled:

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

Comment: For the latest syntax of the `"script"` param, check [Update the document source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-source)

Answer (score 3):

Following up on datashovel answer you should use Elasticsearch [scrolling API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) to fetched the desired documents and then using bulk update (or not) update the documents.

Assuming your index is `users` and doc_type is `user` that would be something like:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/users/user/_search?scroll=1m' -d '
{
    "constant_score": {
        "filter" : {
           "term" : {
               "temp" : 1
           }
        }
    }
}'
```

Which will return a scroll_id (something like `c2Nhbjs2OzM0NDg1ODpzRlBLc0FXNlNyNm5JWUc1`) which then you should use for iterating over the results, doing:

```
curl -XGET  'localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=1m' \
    -d 'c2Nhbjs2OzM0NDg1ODpzRlBLc0FXNlNyNm5JWUc1'
```

Until there aren't any hits.

While iterating you should create a list for bulk updating, containing all the elements returned by the scrolling.

```
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "user", "_index" : "users"} }
{ "doc" : {"temp" : 0} }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "2", "_type" : "user", "_index" : "users"} }
{ "doc" : {"temp" : 0} }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "3", "_type" : "user", "_index" : "users"} }
{ "doc" : {"temp" : 0} }
```

(You can see more detail on how to do this on the [bulk api docs](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html))

I don't know any PHP but the Elasticsearch PHP API [Elastica](http://elastica.io/) has some helper functions for [scrolling](http://elastica.io/api/classes/Elastica.ScanAndScroll.html) and [bulk](http://elastica.io/api/classes/Elastica.Bulk.html).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. This route is new to me so it shall take me some time to research. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

If you would want to write a dynamic "update query" (like your example) you would write a script which would tell ElasticSearch the logic to follow when transforming the values.

There are some useful examples of that here:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

Comment: I understand slightly, but I don't know how to begin with selecting the desired items to be updated. And I can't find in the second link how to do it to more than one item at a time?

Comment: Keep in mind that a relational database and document-based datastore are solving different problems.  If you need the kind of performance you get out of a relational database for fast / efficient updates of all records you should probably use relational database for those kinds of problems.

Comment: And another thing to keep in mind is that ElasticSearch is built to be used in distributed architecture, so you can't necessarily rely on the same guarantees in bulk updates that you're probably used to in a relational database.  A good option for bulk updates is the Scroll API mentioned below by @vierja.